# Problem with Reusable polymer based component on Cypress.io UI automation

Tags: polymer-1.0, cypress

In our application, html 'input' tag is wrapped and named  as lets say 'input-app'
We are  using 'input-app' in different places in same html page and I am not able to do cy.get().type() on unique input tag as 'input-app' tag has 'input' which is having same ids.
Do not want to change 'input-app' component definition. What is solution to it?

Comment: Would it help if you showed some HTML?

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing your wrapped input-app should not have the same id on every input,but it seems we are pass that point. Are there any other div elements that are parents of this wrapped input?

```
cy.get('THE_PARENT_ID').find('input').type('what you need to type')
```

If you can't change the component can you put your own id on the element that is wrapping it. for instance

```
<input-app id='YOUR_ID'></input-app> 

cy.get('#YOUR_ID').find('input').type('what you need to type')
```